# vim - how to get file with folds

Tags: vim

I am trying to use fold feature of vim. I could fold the text in vim ( used commands zc/zo/zM).

After saving the file with folds, when I re-open, file is shown without any folds.
I want to see a file with folds.

I even installed foldplugin for vim. But this problem persists.

How to get a file with folds in vim, when I re-open the file?
Pls advise.

Thank  you,

Comment: Seems like you have some options not set the way you wish. Please report the result of this command: `:set fen? fdl? fdls?` (I suspect `nofoldenable`...) Also, which `foldmethod` is your file using?

Comment: :set fen? - foldenable :set fdl? - foldlevel=0 :set fdls? - foldlevelstart=1 and my foldmethod is indent

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142402/546861

Comment: hi rominl, I tried the solution given there i.e.  Adding this to the top of vimrc

let &viewdir=expand("$HOME") . "/.bk/.vim/viewdir"
if !isdirectory(expand(&viewdir))|call mkdir(expand(&viewdir), "p", 451)|endif and adding below autocmd BufWrite * mkview
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * silent loadview

Answer (score 1):

1. turn on the folding in .vimirc

   > set foldenable
2. set foldmethod

   use the marker method, add the following line in .vimrc

   > set foldmethod=marker
3. vim support indent, marker, manual, syntax, expr foldmethod

see below links for more details:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html

Comment: I got solution from Drew Neil. Link is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3660640/128850. Vim does not save folds. So, you need to save session and restore to view the folds.